# Writing more than one String to a file without deleting the first one ANDROID favorites for browser

Tags: java, android

I am making a simple browser for school and I am trying to make the favorites. This code here adds a favorite to a file(so I can keep it after the app is closed) and displays it in the TextView. My problem is that it can only save one. If i add the second one, the first one is replaced. I thought i could add them in an array or arrayList(or anything that works, i am open to suggestions), but i can't succeed. Thanks for the help.

```
 package com.example.browser3;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Favorite extends Activity {
EditText etName;
EditText etAdress;
Button bAdd;
TextView tvDisplay;




protected void onResume() {
    readFile("favorite.txt", tvDisplay);
    super.onResume();
}

public void writeFile(String fileName, EditText v, EditText x){

    try {
        OutputStreamWriter out=new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput(fileName,0));
        out.write(v.getText().toString()+ x.getText().toString());

        out.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void readFile(String fileName, TextView w){
    try {
        InputStream in=openFileInput(fileName);
        if(in!=null){
            InputStreamReader reader= new InputStreamReader(in);
            BufferedReader buffreader= new BufferedReader(reader);

            StringBuilder builder= new StringBuilder();
            String str;
            while((str=buffreader.readLine())!=null){
                builder.append(str+ "\n");
            }
            in.close();
            w.setText(builder.toString());
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.favorite);


    etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etName);
    etAdress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAdress);
    bAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
    tvDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay);

    bAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            writeFile("favorite.txt",etName, etAdress);
            readFile("favorite.txt", tvDisplay);
        }

    });

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to write at first position i.e. prepend then u need to use this

```
     private void writeToFile(Context context,String data){
         try{
             String path=context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();

             File file = new File(path + File.separator + fileName);
             RandomAccessFile rf = new RandomAccessFile(file,"rws"); 
             file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
                Log.d("creating file path",path);

                byte[] text = new byte[(int) file.length()];
                rf.readFully(text);
                rf.seek(0);
                rf.writeBytes(data);
                rf.write(text);
                Log.d("write","writing file...");
                rf.close();




         }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace(); Log.d("caught", "data wititng fail");} 
     }
```

and if u want to append use this

```
     private void writeToFile(Context context,String data){
         try{
             String path=context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();

             File file = new File(path + File.separator + fileName);
             RandomAccessFile rf = new RandomAccessFile(file,"rws"); 
             file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
                Log.d("creating file path",path);

                byte[] text = new byte[(int) file.length()];
                rf.readFully(text);
                rf.seek(0);
                 rf.write(text);
                rf.writeBytes(data);

                Log.d("write","writing file...");
                rf.close();                     


         }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace(); Log.d("caught", "data wititng fail");} 
     }
```

or u can open file in MODE_APPEND mode.. to open file in append mode change to this `OutputStreamWriter out=new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput(fileName,true));`

Comment: Thanks for answering. I tried what you said, but i don't think I did it right because it doesn't work. Actually, i am sure i did it wrong. I can't really understand what you did there. Here is the code, i hope it doesn't make you laugh.I didn't know what to put in the Context parameter so I left it null.

Comment: bAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    String adresa=etAdress.getText().toString();
    
    writeToFile( null, adresa);
    
    readFile("favorites.txt",tvDisplay);
    
   }

  });

Comment: Okay ill help u just wait fr a min

Comment: I am not able to understand what u did.. Can u put your code in your question

Comment: And if u feel this is right answer than mark it as answer